# Using one class instead of another

Tags: .net

I remember .Net had a feature (don't remember whether it was a configuration option or assemby attribute) which would replace one class with another.

For example I have `AmbiguousClass` in some referenced assembly which uses locale-unaware strings. What I want to do is inherit `AmbiguousClass` with `LocalizedAmbiguousClass` and point to .Net that whenever `AmbiguousClass` is created or used a `LocalizedAmbiguousClass` should be used instead.

I remember something like that was mentioned in preparation for Microsoft 70-536 certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're referring to the [TypeForwardedToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177220.aspx), but I don't think that this will achieve your goal, as you're creating a whole new type, instead of moving the same type to another assembly (or namespace).

If you're instantiating your 'AmbiguousClass' using a factory, then you have a single point in your code where you'll have to modify your code (because I think that this is really what you'll have to do).  If you are not using some kind of factory, then I think you're facing a tough job. 
(Although Resharper could help you with this one :) ).

Comment: That is exactly the attribute I couldn't remember. It seems I couldn't remember what it really does as well :)